# Display the signup time of the User ( member since )

Tags: python, django, django-models, time

I am building a Blog WebApp and I am trying to implement a Feature.

**What i am trying to do :-**

I am trying to display the `Date or Time of user's signup` (Like stack overflow does (member since 2 months))

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,default='',unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,default='')
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def age(self):
        current_datetime = datetime.now(tz=datetime.timezone.utc)
        return (current_datetime - self.time).days
```

template.html

```
{{ request.user.profile.time }}
```

Comment: is 'time' field the signup datetime of the user?

Comment: Yes, It's only for `sign-up time of the user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `property` in models. By using this you will be able to fetch `age` everytime you query `Profile` model

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='', unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    @property
    def age(self):
        current_datetime = datetime.now()
        #current_datetime = datetime.now(timezone.utc)  for tz aware datetimes
        return (current_datetime - self.time).days
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231169/discussion-between-neeraj-and-test).

Answer (score 1):

You could use `django-model-utils`. To be more specific create model that inherit `TimeStampedModel`.

To render "since " you could use `django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize`.

To use directly in code:

```
humanize.naturaltime(datetime.datetime.now() - yourmodelinstance.created)
```

To use in template:

```
{% load humanize %}

{{ yourmodelinstance.created | naturaltime }}
```

Your example would look like:

```
import datetime
from django.contrib.humanize.templatetags import humanize
from model_utils.models import TimeStampedModel

class Profile(TimeStampedModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default='', unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')

    @property
    def age(self):
        return humanize.naturaltime(datetime.datetime.now() - self.created)
```

To get rid of alot of milisecond You could replace age property return value with:

```
@property
def age(self):
    return humanize.naturaltime(datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0) - self.created.replace(microsecond=0)
```